# How do I maintain jquery functions on loaded code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `modals` that have been loaded to my other pages, except the first one. I did this to save time.

This is the code that loads my modals

```
$(function () {
    $('#header').load('reusenavbar.php');
    $('#loginModal').load('reuseloginmodal.php');
    $('#regModal').load('reuseregistermodal.php');
    $('#postAdModal').load('reusepostadmodal.php');
});
```

These load fine, but there are a few challenges.

The first error I got was `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` from this code;

```
document.querySelector('#ad_img_select').addEventListener("change", previewImages); //first code, works fine on hard coded code, but not on loaded code
```

The code below got rid of the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` by doing this.

```
$('#ad_img_select').on("change", previewImages); //my solution
```

It works fine when hard coded but not on loaded code.

Comment: The error means that `#ad_img_select` does not exist in the DOM at the point you execute that line of code. Is it contained in the HTML you inject using `load()`? If so you need to use the callback argument of that method.

Comment: you may use event delegation with pure `JS` or `$(document).on("change", '#ad_img_select', previewImages)`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this code loaded before this script

Comment: If that worked it means that your elements are not loaded before the script. Remember that `load()` is asynchronous. In either case, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue.

```
$(document).on("change", '#ad_img_select', previewImages)
```